# Invalid column name for table type parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, ssrs-2008

I have a table type which is used in a stored procedure to filter out values.

```
CREATE TYPE PackageIdType AS TABLE   
( 
     PackageId VARCHAR(150)  
);
```

My stored procedure is this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spLocalGetValuesFromTable]    
     @RundateStart datetime,
     @RundateEnd datetime,
     @CreationIds PackageIdType READONLY  
AS
     SELECT * 
     FROM MYTABLE 
     WHERE date BETWEEN @RundateStart AND @RundateEnd 
       AND Ids IN (@CreationIds)
```

But when I run this getting error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure spLocalGetValuesFromTable, Line --[Batch Start Line 0]
>   Invalid column name '@CreationIds'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a table, so the correct syntax would be

```
SELECT *
FROM  MYTABLE
WHERE date Between @RundateStart And @RundateEnd 
  AND Ids in (SELECT PackageId FROM @CreationIds)
```

This assumes that each row in the table `@CreationIds` is an Id that can map to the same type as `Ids` in `MYTABLE`.